# how can ı install ubuntu 20.04 in m1 MacBook

Tags: macbook, ros

In order to work with ros, I need to install ubuntu on my m1 macbook device, and as I learned from the internet, ros is supported by ubuntu 20.04 version. I had previously installed the ubuntu 23 version and I did this with utm because it gave an error with virtualbox. When I looked at the m1 ubuntu20.04 installation versions on the internet, it seemed like it was installed in a different way than the one I installed myself, and I wasn't sure if I was doing it right. Has anyone experienced this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to [Asahi Linux](https://asahilinux.org/)! M1 uses a custom boot process, and many procedures are different from x86. See [Ubuntu Asahi's website](https://ubuntuasahi.org) for installation instructions.